# How to get the path of a file, in an absolut way

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, path

If I am in **/home/usr** and I call python **/usr/local/rcom/bin/something.py**

How can I make the script inside **something.py** know he resides in **/usr/local/rcom/bin**?
The `os.path.abspath` is calculated with the `cwd` which is **/home/usr** in this case.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on the `__file__` attribute of your script/module.

```
import os

path, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print path
```

prints

```
 /usr/local/rcom/bin
```

if executed in your `something.py`.

EDIT: Yes, you need to consider the absolute path ;-), i.e. `os.path.abspath`

Answer (score 0):

Inside something.py:

```
import os
print os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Note that this will only work if you call something.py using it's absolute path. If you use a relative path (ex. scripts/something.py) you need to change the code to:

```
import os
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```